# Safely opening a suspect USB Drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive, virus-removal

If you have a USB Drive that may or may not be contaminated, what is the best way to retrieve data from it without reinfecting yourself?

Comment: Related: [How can I browse an untrusted USB flash drive safely?](//superuser.com/q/983709/150988),  [Is there any way to safely examine the contents of a USB memory stick?](//security.stackexchange.com/q/103088/34757),  [What is the danger of inserting and browsing an untrusted USB drive?](/q/709275/150988),  [How can a flash drive spread a virus?](/q/93939/150988),  and  [How can USB sticks be dangerous?](//security.stackexchange.com/q/102873/34757), and probably more.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to be completely sure, mount it on a Mac or Linux box. Seriously.

For an example, see the new shortcut icon exploit, which ALL Windows machines since NT have been vulnerable to. This exploit allows arbitrary code to be executed simply when the folder is opened. No Autorun required. No manual execution required. It infects the system as soon as the folder is opened.

http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/Threat/Encyclopedia/Entry.aspx?Name=Exploit%3AWin32%2FCplLnk.A

If you don't have a real *nix (includes Mac) box, just boot from a LiveCD. You may want to scan with [Clam AntiVirus](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/) while you're at it too.

Comment: +1 - If it's a Windows machine, load it on OSX or Linux, or a Windows box you don't care about.

Comment: Absolutely!
May want to edit this post to include running from a LiveCD in case there isn't a Linux box handy. Then scan with Clam

Comment: *Completely* safe, because macOS and Linux are invulnerable to malware? No. Seriously. They are less vulnerable, maybe, but [Linux is ***not*** immune to viruses](https://www.linux.com/learn/myth-busting-linux-immune-viruses). If you disconnect all your storage devices (HDDs, SSDs, etc.) and your network connection, and boot from a LiveCD, then maybe you are relatively safe from malware.

Answer (score 7):

The first thing you absolutely need to do is disable autorun. There is a good tutorial [here](http://antivirus.about.com/od/securitytips/ht/autorun.htm).

If it were me though, I'd boot to a non-writable OS (e.g. [Knoppix](http://www.knoppix.net/)) and copy the data off that way. Knoppix is outstanding for this sort of recovery.

Answer (score 7):

Mount it on a computer booted off of a Linux live boot CD and the hard drives (and any other USB drives too) disconnected.

Comment: +1 for taking [the accepted answer](/q/167878/150988#167881) and improving it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows then disable auto-run.

How to disable autorun: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967715

Answer (score 1):

Holding the left shift while inserting the drive will temporarily disable autorun

Comment: It is however not the most reliable method I have seen.

Answer (score 0):

Disable auto-run as mentioned by Daisetsu and use the Command Prompt which won't be exploited.